# Understanding static cast for constructors of classes

Tags: c++, class, static

My question is, I have a program that uses statically casts the constructor object to a `char` type. The line is `char c1 = static_cast<char>(Hazem)`. What happens here exactly? Also why does the line `Hazem = static_cast<A>(a)` have an output just by being called?

Thank you

```
class A {
    int x;
public:
    A(int i) {

        x = i;

        cout << "Conversion constructor" << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    operator char()
    {
        cout << "Conversion operator" << endl;
        return char(x);
    }

};

int main() {

    A Hazem(65);
    Hazem = 66;

    char c1 = static_cast<char>(Hazem);
    cout << c1 << endl;


    int a = 30;
    Hazem = static_cast<A>(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```cpp
Conversion constructor
65
Conversion constructor
66
Conversion operator
B
Conversion constructor
30
```

Comment: White space may not matter to the compiler, but it does to humans. When sharing code, please be sure that it is formatted to be as easy to read as possible.

Comment: Do you know what `static_cast` is, and what it does?

Comment: Do you know what the `operator char()` member of class `A` does and when it will be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a program that uses statically casts the constructor object to a char type.

There is no such thing as a "constructor object". I think you just mean… "object"?

A constructor is a special type of member function.

> The line is `char c1 = static_cast<char>(Hazem)`. What happens here exactly?

What you asked the computer to make happen: to follow the steps described in `operator char()` in producing a `char`. Those steps are:

- produce the console output "Conversion operator"
- return the value of member variable `x` as cast to `char`

> Also why does the line `Hazem = static_cast<A>(a)` have an output just by being called?

Because, again, that's what you asked the computer to do. Your *constructor* taking `int` has the following steps:

- set the value of the member `x` to the argument `i`
- **produce the console output "Conversion constructor"**
- **produce the console output `x`**

…and `static_cast<A>(a)` *constructs* an `A` from the argument `a` (here, an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

char c1 = static_cast(Hazem) you are doing a cast to char of the value int 66 that in ASCII Is letter 'B' .

Hazem = static_cast(a) you are called  the constructor with value 30, while Doing  this assignment and so you print the value of member variabile x